# Is there a way to filter Maven's dependency:tree by scope?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm trying to filter the output of `dependency:tree` by scope. The docs (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) specify a `<scope>` option that does exactly this, but it's currently broken due to a long-outstanding bug. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

I have a same problem. The only way I can try is this for filtering `test` scope.

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose | grep -v ':test'
```